# Additional Text Added to Filename Using Powershell Rename-Item

Tags: windows, powershell, file

I am using Powershell 7.2.1 on a stand alone Win10 machine.

The test is renaming 3 text files from a script. Everything is working except the renamed file names have text strings True/False prepended to the intended file names. The filenames should NOT have "True False" or "True True" before them.

```
True False AALTONEN-ALLAN_PENCARROW_PAGE
True False COVER_PAGE_PENCARROW_1981
True True BARTLETT-BEDGGOOD-BEECH-BEST_PENCARROW_PAGE_-
```

These names have been copied/pasted from File Explorer (view Details, sort Name) The .txt extension is not shown.

They were renamed from these names:

```
Copy of 31832_226140__0001-00002
Copy of 31832_226140__0001-00003
Copy of 31832_226140__0001-00006
```

The relevant line in my Powershell script is:

```
# use the filename to rename this file
Rename-Item -Path $item -NewName $fileName
```

I have used -Whatif parameter `Rename-Item -Path $item -NewName $fileName -Whatif` Here's the output split over two lines.

```
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\test\test3\Copy of 31832_226140__0001-00003.txt
Destination: C:\test\test3\True False AALTONEN-ALLAN_PENCARROW_PAGE_1".
```

I have added Write-Host lines throughout the process to check the variable outputs. And everything is correct up until the `Rename-Item` code.

I have looked at the documentation and can't see that any additional parameters are required for the Rename-Item cmdlet in my application. But I could be missing something here.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not following what's the question you have or where are you having difficulties?

Comment: The filenames should NOT have "True False" or "True True" before them.

Comment: You would need to add the actual code you're using to rename them in that case.

Comment: Let me clarify, we don't know how `$fileName` is generated and this is the most relevant part of the code and what would be needed for us to help you

Comment: Yes Santiago you are correct. When building my file names I was checking that name strings were not empty. I had cast [bool]string globally! What a chump I am. Thank you. BTW I think there is a little too much code, in my file name building region, for SO. Apologies for any misunderstandings.

Comment: Glad to here you got it resolved. This is why SO needs an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example). Sometimes it is a lot of work to create an MRE. I find that often the effort to create the MRE reveals the problem.